# Trying to make a function in that will replace the names of certain character strings to a different character string when a dataframe is fed into it

Tags: r, function

I have a couple datasets with similar information, and I want to create a function that will replace certain character string occurrences with a different character string when the datasets are fed into it. I made the code for the function below:

```
check_names <- function(x) {
  ifelse(daisy_final[daisy_final == "Bosmina (bosmina) liederi"])
    yes = daisy_final[daisy_final == "Bosmina (bosmina) liederi"] <- "Bosmina liederi"
    no = return(table(daisy_final$taxa_name))
  ifelse(daisy_final[daisy_final == "Bosmina (bosmina) freyi"])
    yes = lapply(daisy_final, function(daisy_final) {gsub("Bosmina (bosmina) freyi", "Bosmina freyi", daisy_final)})
    no = return(table(daisy_final$taxa_name))
  ifelse(daisy_final[daisy_final == "B. Freyi, liederi or longirostris"])
    yes = daisy_final[daisy_final == "B. Freyi, liederi or longirostris"] <- "Bosmina spp."
    no = return(table(daisy_final$taxa_name))
  ifelse(daisy_final[daisy_final == "Copepodid-calanoid or cyclopoid"])
    yes = daisy_final[daisy_final == "Copepodid-calanoid or cyclopoid"] <- "NA"
    no = return(table(daisy_final$taxa_name))
 ifelse(daisy_final[daisy_final == "Daphnia (daphnia) ambigua"])
    yes = daisy_final[daisy_final == "Daphnia (daphnia) ambigua"] <- "Daphnia ambigua"
    no = return(table(daisy_final$taxa_name))
 ifelse(daisy_final[daisy_final == "Daphnia (daphnia) catawba"])
    yes = daisy_final[daisy_final == "Daphnia (daphnia) catawba"] <- "Daphnia catawba"
    no = return(table(daisy_final$taxa_name))
  ifelse(daisy_final[daisy_final == "Daphnia (daphnia) pulex"])
    yes = daisy_final[daisy_final == "Daphnia (daphnia) pulex"] <- "Daphnia pulex"
    no = return(table(daisy_final$taxa_name))
  ifelse(daisy_final[daisy_final == "Daphnia (daphnia) retrocurva"])
    yes = daisy_final[daisy_final == "Daphnia (daphnia) retrocurva"] <- "Daphnia retrocurva"
    no = return(table(daisy_final$taxa_name))
  ifelse(daisy_final[daisy_final == "Daphnia (hyalodaphnia) dubia"])
    yes = daisy_final[daisy_final == "Daphnia (hyalodaphnia) dubia"] <- "Hyalodaphnia dubia"
    no = return(table(daisy_final$taxa_name))
  ifelse(daisy_final[daisy_final == "Daphnia (hyalodaphnia) longiremis"])
    yes = daisy_final[daisy_final == "Daphnia (hyalodaphnia) longiremis"] <- "Hyalodaphnia longiremis"
    no = return(table(daisy_final$taxa_name))
  ifelse(daisy_final[daisy_final == "Daphnia (hyalodaphnia) galeata mendotae"])
    yes = daisy_final[daisy_final == "Daphnia (hyalodaphnia) galeata mendotae"] <- "Hyalodaphnia galeata mendotae"
    no = return(table(daisy_final$taxa_name))
  ifelse(daisy_final[daisy_final == "Eubosmina (eubosmina) longispina"])
    yes = daisy_final[daisy_final == "Eubosmina (eubosmina) longispina"] <- "Eubosmina longispina"
    no = return(table(daisy_final$taxa_name))
  ifelse(daisy_final[daisy_final == "Eubosmina (eubosmina) sp."])
    yes = daisy_final[daisy_final == "Eubosmina (eubosmina) sp."] <- "Eubosmina sp."
    no = return(table(daisy_final$taxa_name))
  ifelse(daisy_final[daisy_final == "Eubosmina (neobosmina) tubicen"])
    yes = daisy_final[daisy_final == "Eubosmina (neobosmina) tubicen"] <- "Neobosmina tubican"
    no = return(table(daisy_final$taxa_name))
  ifelse(daisy_final[daisy_final == "Nauplius-calanoid or cyclopoid"])
    yes = daisy_final[daisy_final == "Nauplius-calanoid or cyclopoid"] <- "NA"
    no = return(table(daisy_final$taxa_name))
  ifelse(daisy_final[daisy_final == "Unidentified rotifer"])
    yes = daisy_final[daisy_final == "Unidentified rotifer"] <- "NA"
    no = return(table(daisy_final$taxa_name))
}

check_names(daisy_final)
```

When I run the function with the `daisy_final` dataset however, only the first `ifelse` function works and Bosmina (bosmina) liederi changes to Bosmina liederi - the rest of the character strings that I want to change remain the same. Is anything glaringly wrong with the code for my function that I'm not seeing?

Comment: What if  you try `gsub("\\(.*\\) ", "", daisy_final)` (assuming `daisy_final` is a vector)?

Comment: @Phil ahh, daisy_final is a dataframe

Comment: You need to apply the changes to the variable in your data frame that has those data points. It would be helpful if you can provide an example of your data set, and your expected outcome.

Comment: @Phil I wish I could post a picture! daisy_final is a dataframe with a column called "taxa_names", and that is the column with certain character strings I want to change in different rows. Expected output is that same dataframe with the updated names in the taxa_names column

Comment: Please don't post a picture. You can use `dput()` with a sample of your data set and post it in your question. In the meantime, try `daisy_final$taxa_names <- gsub("\\(.*\\) ", "", daisy_final$taxa_names)`